# Getting Real-Time Sensor Data from Smart Watches

Tags: android, swift, flutter, mobile, watch

I'm wondering what's the most effective way of getting smart watch sensor data in intervals (say every 30 mins) in order to show in my mobile app. Due to the restrictions each watch OS has in place, finding the respective SDKs and APIs is more difficult than ever now. I have no problem developing a separate app for making this happen, as long I make sure respective sensors get activated upon fetching data without user intervention. Any suggestions?